# ferrite core replacements with passives

Tags: noise, emc, ferrite

I am using a ferrite core to remove video noise in an NTSC video system. I am using the ferrite core on the video and video GND lines.

I am merely winding the video and video GND lines on the ferrite core. The core used is - [this](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/223/LFB290190-000-607221.pdf).

The impedance charachteristics is as shown below -

[image: Impedance curve]

Now, analog video consists of a base-band signal of approx 5Mhz. I was connecting 2 different video sources to the same connector on my board. The video signals come to the connector as shown below -

[image: Video conn].

Now, I kept observing a lot of roll noise on both my video signals. Now,I coiled the 2 video lines (and their respective GNDs) over 2 independent ferrite cores. This absolutely removed the roll noise and made the video very clean. I gave about 8 turns on the torroid. How did that happen ? How does a ferrite core work ?

Also, can I acheive the same impedance charachteristics using passives ?

Comment: That means you hace common mode interference. Check your star grounding of the system. A choke _IS_ a passive element.

Comment: @winny. Thank you for the reply. Can I acheive the same with inductors and caps ?

Comment: Your common mode choke _IS_ an inductor. Why do you want to get rid of it?

Comment: @winny , the physical dimensions of the choke is killing me. I wanted to achieve the same in small packages.

Comment: No problem. Get a thinner wire and smaller core or get yourself a very small PCB mounted common mode choke. Also, how do you ground your entire setup?

Comment: If you wind two video signals around the same core, you have created a transformer. This means that the signals are coupled together by the core. This explains why you had problems with both signals on one core. The part you are looking for is a common-mode choke for video.

Comment: How many turns are you using in the "good" configuration?